# How to drag something behind another view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to write a calendar like custom view as described in this blog post, which is also kind of like an Excel spreadsheet.  Headers on the top and column counts on the left.  Those are stickied to the top and left

https://danielrampelt.com/blog/jetpack-compose-custom-schedule-layout-part-1/

Unlike this blog post, which adds a horizontal / vertical scroll modifier on the content which keeps the headers in place works, I need to be able to drag my content in all directions.

It looked like I needed to use a `pointInput` with a `detectDragGestures`, but when I use that, it drags like i want, the headers are pinned to the top and move left/right and the column counts are pinned to the left and move up and down

But the schedule content scrolls over the columns/headers as i drag them upwards or left.

I need the dragged content to go behind the header/column indicators.

My layout is like this

```
var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

Column(
    modifier = modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consumeAllChanges()
                offsetX = (offsetX + dragAmount.x).coerceIn((-1 * unitWidth.toPx() * unitList.count()), 0f)
                offsetY = (offsetY + dragAmount.y).coerceIn(-1 * hourHeight.toPx() * 24, 0f)
            }
        }
  ) {

      Header(modifier = Modifier.offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), 0) } )
          
      Row(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            SideBar( modifier = Modifier.offset { IntOffset(0, offsetY.roundToInt())})
            Schedule( modifier = Modifier.offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt() + unitWidth.roundToPx(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }.weight(1f)) } )
      )
 }
```

How do I enable dragging in any direction, and not overlap the other views?  I want the content to be hidden / vanish behind the headers as it goes into them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the z-index of the headers and stuff to something like 5 and that of the draggable to a lower value. It will automatically be clipped upon appropriate position attainment

Comment: I am not sure but I think just setting the z-index of a the headers to one and leaving the rest of the code untouched should also do the trick

Comment: That was it!  I set the headers to 1 and they go behind it now.  Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. :)